# How to simplify a range of repeated lines into an array (or any way possible)

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a script that I am working on:

```
function doc_keyDown(e) {
 if (e.key === "q") {document.getElementById("area").value += "ф";}
 if (e.key === "Q") {document.getElementById("area").value += "Ф";}
 if (e.key === "w") {document.getElementById("area").value += "ц";}
 if (e.key === "W") {document.getElementById("area").value += "Ц";}
 if (e.key === "e") {document.getElementById("area").value += "у";}
 if (e.key === "E") {document.getElementById("area").value += "У";}
 if (e.key === "r") {document.getElementById("area").value += "ж";}
 if (e.key === "R") {document.getElementById("area").value += "Ж";}
return false;
}
document.addEventListener(doc_keyDown, false);
```

The aim of this code is to create an online keyboard, which types a foreign alphabet by typing in a  Latin alphabet.

Which means, I need more than 50 of the `if` codes above, and I am certain that there is a way to shorten this redundant repetition.

One thing that I have considered is using an array, which I referred to many sources such as [this one](https://javascript.info/array), and I expect the result to look like the example below, but due to not being experienced with arrays, I do not know how to make this work.

```
var conversion = {
"q":"ф",
"Q":"Ф",
"w":"ц",
"W":"Ц",
...
```

And not only for arrays, I would like to learn any better ways to simplify the repeated lines. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: switch case should be a good choice here https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: @Alex Haven't heard about the code review page, and I'll have a look at the switch case. Thanks

Comment: I think simple mapping for letter to symbol would work

Comment: @Also what you could think about doing two corresponding arrays one with the latin alphabet and one with the other values. the values have to be at the same index.
Then check in a loop at which position is it in the array and return the value out of the other array

Comment: You could use a Hash Map or any equivalent structure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you are using an object not an array. This is rather simple to use you don't even need any loops.

```js
var conversion = {
  "q": "ф",
  "Q": "Ф",
  "w": "ц",
  "W": "Ц"
}

area = document.getElementById("area");

function doc_keyDown(e) {

  newkey = conversion[e.key]
  if (newkey) {
    area.value = area.value.split(e.key).join(newkey);
  }

  return false;
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", doc_keyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("keydown", doc_keyDown, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="area">
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, except that the snippet seems to render two alphabets at once.

Comment: @Henry5400, what do you mean it renders two alphabets at once?

Comment: instead of concat replace

Comment: @imvain2 when you type in q then the q and the symbol appears. But only the symbol should appear

Comment: @imvain2 I'm experiencing what Alex has explained ;)

Comment: I updated my answer to use keyup and replace the value instead of appending it

Comment: @imvain2 Thanks!

Comment: The code seems to have another problem, when a key is pressed long enough and types more than one alphabets, it only converts the first alphabet.

Comment: @Henry5400 that is a problem with javascript's replace function. I have updated my answer.